# Transport functions, lemmas between isomorphic structures using Univalence

Tags: proof-verification, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

According to the HoTT book page 153, we can get functions and lemmas with ease using univalence. For example, in order to get the $\mathsf{double}'$ function  (i.e., the double function for $\mathbb{N}'$) from $\mathsf{double}$ (for $\mathbb{N}$), we can just use the function

$$
 \mathsf{transport} : (B : A \to \mathcal{U})\to (p : x \equiv y) \to (B x \to B y),
$$

and Univalence

$$ 
\mathsf{ua} : (A,\, B : \mathcal{U}) \to (A \simeq B) \to A \equiv_{\mathcal{U}} B.
$$

Let's say, given the quasi-inverse $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}'$ and $g : \mathbb{N}' \to \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathsf{double} : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

How to get $\mathsf{double}' : \mathbb{N}'\to \mathbb{N}'$ using the stuff above? Or maybe we should use path induction instead of transport?

Resource:

https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT-Agda/blob/master/core/lib/Base.agda

Comment: The reference you gave us it's seems to be outdated, could you please update it? @doofin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Welcome to Math.SE!* Please try to use $\LaTeX$ in your questions to make the math more readable, and also to give as precise citations as possible for future reference. Could you improve your question in these regards?

*To the math:* As stated in the book, the key is to view the structure or theorem you are interested in as a type-indexed family and to use transport to move the structure/theorem along the fibres. Here, you'd like to construct a double function $\text{double}^{\prime}: {\mathbb N}^{\prime}\to {\mathbb N}^{\prime}$ from the known double function $\text{double}: {\mathbb N}\to {\mathbb N}$. The point is that these can be viewed as elements in the fiber of ${\mathbb N}^{\prime}$ resp. ${\mathbb N}$ of the family $(\sum\limits_{T:{\mathcal U}} T\to T)\to{\mathcal U}$ corresponding to $P: {\mathcal U}\to {\mathsf {Type}},\ T\mapsto (T\to T)$, and a witness of equality $e: T=T^{\prime}$ gives rise to an equivalence of the fibres $P(T)=(T\to T)\simeq P(T^{\prime})=(T^{\prime}\to T^{\prime})$ by transport. If you apply this to the equality ${\mathbb N}={\mathbb N}^{\prime}$ which you have deduced from some equivalence ${\mathbb N}\simeq {\mathbb N}^{\prime}$ via univalence, you get $({\mathbb N}\to {\mathbb N})\simeq ({\mathbb N}^{\prime}\to {\mathbb N}^{\prime})$ into which you can plug $\text{double}: {\mathbb N}\to {\mathbb N}$ to get some $\text{double}^{\prime} : {\mathbb N}^{\prime}\to {\mathbb N}^{\prime}$.

Let me know if you need more explanations.

Comment: Sorry for the poor writing.. But what transport gives is P(x)≃P(y) , not clear how to get something like (T→T)≃(T′→T′)

Comment: The point is that you have chosen $P$ such that $P(T) = (T\to T)$.

Comment: Thanks for the first edit, it would be great if you could also improve the $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @doofin Do you have more questions?

Comment: Thanks for your heuristic explanation! But as a beginner for dependent types,I have no idea how to define P(T) reasonably,making it type as (T->T).Maybe i can define something like:P(T) \x->if x is typed N' then succ' else succ,but using nature number constructors here seems idiomatic..

Comment: @doofin You're confused about what $P$ is; in this case, you simply need to define $P(T)$ *as* $T \to T$, and then you're done.  That is, there is no more to it than $\forall T : \mathcal{U}, P(T) = (T \to T)$.